# Что такое statless bean и stateful bean в контексте Spring

Tags: java, spring, bean

Не могу понять смысл слов stateful and stateless. Какими характеристиками обладают бины, имеющие такие состояния и что вообще подразумевается под состоянием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Бины без состояния(`Stateless`): бины, которые являются одиночными и
   инициализируются только один раз (`Singleton`). Единственное состояние, которое у
   них есть, - это общее состояние. Эти bean-компоненты создаются во
   время инициализации `ApplicationContext`. Тот же экземпляр
   bean-компонента будет возвращен / введен в течение времени
   существования этого `ApplicationContext`.
2. Бины с состоянием(`Stateful`): бины, которые могут нести состояние (переменные
   экземпляра). Они создаются КАЖДЫЙ раз, когда требуется объект
   (например, при использовании оператора «`new`» в java).